# (-212:Parsing error) Unsupported activation: mish in function 'ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am new to object detetctio and trying to run code for simple object detection on google colab, please help me with the solution

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
from numpy.lib.polynomial import poly

img = cv2.imread("/content/banner.jpg")
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.show()
box, label,count = cv.detect_common_objects(img)
#output = draw_bbox(img, box,label, count)
```

but it is giving error as

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:552: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unsupported activation: mish in function 'ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running object detection on Yolov4?
If yes, please note that Yolov4 is not supported by Opencv 4.2.0 and 4.3.0.
Try to download the last version in master branch support YoloV4 (according to [KyloEntro](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17479))

Personally, I have upgraded opencv-python to version 4.5.3.56, and there is no more error!

Answer (score 0):

please update your opencv, more recent versions have a proper mish activation

```
import cvlib as cv
```

DONT use 3rd party libs built on top of opencv, since you have no control about versioning, and noone knows about those enough to help you